# Prerequisites for Callaghan's Advanced Calculus

Tags: reference-request

A few months ago I got hold of a cheap copy of this book. It's quite an advanced book and I was wondering if there is some other book that I should read first, which would lead nicely into Callaghan's book.

Background: I study math just as a hobby. I am familiar with single variable calculus and undergraduate-level real analysis.

Comment: If you are familiar with real analysis, you don't need anything before starting the book.

Comment: I looked at the table of contents and some other pages available at amazon.com, and I believe Serge Lang's [**Calculus of Several Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387964053) would be pretty good choice to read first. For your purposes, any earlier edition of Lang's book should be fine, by the way (earlier used editions will be cheaper). [These comments about Lang's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1901199/13130) may be of interest.